# In perl my fork process terminates with ""Undefined subroutine &main::fatal called at wrapper.pl"

Tags: perl, fork

In my main program I fork the child using:

```
pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
   exec("$wrapper_file $hours_run");
   exit 0;
}
```

and do some other work.

and in my wrapper file:

```
$test_run = time();
while ($test_run < $hours_run) {
     do $node_grp_submit; # -------------------->script does some work
     sleep 30;
     $test_run = time();
}
```

The script works fine if I run it for 4 hours.

But if I run for longer durations (say 5-8 hours) my wrapper script terminates with 
`Undefined subroutine &main::fatal called at wrapper.pl`.

Comment: Also try `perl -MCarp::Always script.pl` to try to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

`fatal()` is not a perl built-in, but it is a commonly used name for a subroutine called for insurmountable ("fatal") errors.  Apparently, something in your script is calling this function, but it does not exist.

What modules are you using in the script?  An author may have done this on purpose, so that you could define a fatal() and catch the error.  If you can't figure out where it's happening, you could add this to wrapper.pl:

```
use YAML::XS;

sub fatal () {
    print Dump caller 1;
    print Dump @_;
    die "FATAL!";
}
```

This will give you some details about where the sub was called from (`Dump caller 1`) and what is in the argument stack.